# The right button of my mouse clicks on release Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mouse, xorg.conf, right-click

I been having the following problem for a long time in Ubuntu 10.10.

**What happens:**
When I right click I see the contextual but when I release this button it automatically clicks on the first option on this menu.

**What *Should* happen:**
Normal behavior. Show the menu and then with left click (or right again) operate on said menu.

**Extra information:**

This is a USB mouse, is not a hardware error, it works in other computers, and in this same one perfectly when in Windows.
This machine have a nvidia card. Using nvidia-current package.
This problem is more prominent in Chromium and Java applications, also in "gnome-terminal".
UPDATE: in Firefox I get the expected behavior.

**I tried already**

*changing the InputDevice section of my xorg,
*changing setting in the BIOS (Asus motherboard) legacy USB support on and off.
*creating another user (clean .profile ,etc)
*log Gnome as "safe-mode" this means that compiz, and all other software isn't running

**known workaround** : click and hold the right button and then release on the chosen menu option.

link with people with the same problem:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1095706

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the last post of the discussion you mentioned? Links to this entry:
[http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=1435048&postcount=5](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=1435048&postcount=5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you described as **known workaround** is a **design decision**.
There seems to be no way to change the default behaviour.

This is also the case in newer Ubuntu versions.

Sources:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+2.0/+bug/320259
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=810597
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1988352
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/178373/mouse-clicks-when-i-release-the-button

Answer (score 4):

I found solution here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10468385&postcount=19

Just made my mouse left-handed and right-handed back again and it worked :)

Comment: It works now in all the windows except gnome terminal. (shoul i use kde?))